# Comparing MongoDB data with Xml data

Tags: ruby, xml, mongodb, mongoid, compare

I need to write test in the below scenario

```
- I have a ruby script to read xml data and store the resultant data in MongoDB.
- I want to write a test, which compares the xml and the imported content in the db and make sure the data in xml and imported data are similar.
```

Consider the below example xml file:

```
<employees>
    <employee>
        <name>xxx</name>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <name>yyy</name>
    </employee>
</employees>

employees (table)
-----------------
name
xxx
yyy

how do i write test for this case?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java, you could make sure your MongoDB documents match your Java objects and then use JAXB to convert to XML.